# Test if method hits the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following method and I want to make sure that it won't hit the database unless the subdomain changes.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  def current_account
    unless @current_account && @current_account.subdomain == request.subdomain
      @current_account = Account.find_by subdomain: request.subdomain
    end
    @current_account
  end
end
```

How can I test the lest one?

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe ApplicationController, type: :controller do
  controller do
    def index
    end
  end

  describe 'current_account' do
    before(:each) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:account, subdomain: 'subdomain1')
      FactoryGirl.create(:account, subdomain: 'subdomain2')
      request.host = 'subdomain1.example.com'
    end

    it 'sets the current_account based on the subdomain' do
      get :index
      expect(subject.send(:current_account).subdomain).to eq('subdomain1')
    end

    it 'changes the current_account when subdomain changes' do
      get :index
      request.host = 'subdomain2.example.com'
      get :index
      expect(subject.send(:current_account).subdomain).to eq('subdomain2')
    end

    xit 'does not hit the database if subdomain does not change' do
      get :index
      # expect to hit the db
      get :index
      # expect to not hit the db
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried `expect(Account).to receive(:find)` with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually install this gem for that purpose:

https://github.com/brigade/db-query-matchers - RSpec matchers for database queries

Example usage:

```
it 'does not make database queries' do
  expect { subject.make_no_queries }.to_not make_database_queries
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was just looking for an answer to this, so maybe someone else will benefit, because I didn't need a gem for what I wanted.

**The gist of the answer is:** If you don't need to count actual database queries or hits (which I didn't, and it looks like OP didn't either), you can just use [spies on a partial double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/basics/spies#spy-on-a-method-on-a-partial-double) to check whether the method that runs the database query is being called. But you always have to make the spy before you run the method you're spying on. And the syntax is `allow(foo).to receive(:bar)` and `expect(foo).to have_received(:bar)`

So the reason that OP's `expect(Account).to receive(:find)` didn't work is because it should have been:

```rb
it 'does not hit the database if subdomain does not change' do
  # SET THE SPY
  allow(Account).to receive(:find)

  get :index
  # expect to hit the db
  expect(Account).to have_received(:find)

  get :index
  # expect to not hit the db
  expect(Account).to_not have_received(:find)
end
```

You *could* get more complex and spy on and count specific queries and such if you needed to, because you can `expect(foo).to have_received(:bar).with(*args).twice` etc. but if you're using ActiveRecord out of the box and your method could make a variety of queries, my guess is that it'll be easier to use a gem to count database hits than to go into the source code yourself to find out what to spy on.